# We have three methods get,put,post in Rest api .Which one to use when and in which scenerio

Tags: java, servlets

In my application I was trying to insert record in db and I nned to update that existing record.but my confusion is that in which scenerio I can use post/put.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST - Create new resource

PUT - Update a resource

GET - Get an existing resource

That's the norm, however, not following that will not prevent you from updating your db.